# Session cookie not being set on Edge (dot net core)

Tags: session, cookies, .net-core, session-cookies, microsoft-edge

Session cookies are being set on Chrome, FireFox and even IE but not on Edge

The browser version is `Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0`

DotNet core version is `2.1`

and the following information is used in my `startup.cs` file

```cs
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  services.Configure < CookiePolicyOptions > (options => {
   options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
   options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
  });

  services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1).AddJsonOptions(options => {
   options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();
  }).AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

  services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

  services.AddSession(o => {
   o.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(80);
   o.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
   o.Cookie.Name = "my-session-cookie";

  });
 }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
  if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
   app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  } else {
   app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
   app.UseHsts();
  }

  app.UseHttpsRedirection();
  app.UseStaticFiles();
  app.UseCookiePolicy();
  app.UseSession();

  app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

  app.UseMvc(routes => {
   routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
  });

  app.UseSpa(spa => {
   spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

   if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
   }
  });
 }
```

Here are some of the things I've tried out so far:

- Adding the `IsEssential` condition to session options
- Removing `CookiePolicyOptions` and `UseCookiePolicy`
- Attempting to add an expiration date to the session cookie (didn't even start the solution)

Comment: Just by chance, are you trying setting the cookie after a new tab/windows has been opened by Edge?

Comment: @PaulCream No, the session cookie should be set directly on the application start
just a FYI, I found what the problem was and i'll post an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `fetch` on **Edge** is causing the `set-cookie` header to not set a cookie on the browser

The solution was to add `credentials: "same-origin"` to the `fetch` options object

**DOT NOT ADD IT TO THE HEADER**

Quotes from [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

> By default, fetch won't send or receive any cookies

That means your have add the credentials object to it so it can set those cookies

> Since Aug 25, 2017. The spec changed the default credentials policy to
>   same-origin.

I guess **Edge** have not implemented that default yet

Here's an example of a working `fetch`

```
fetch(link, {
  body: JSON.stringify(myDataObject),
  method: "POST",
  credentials: "same-origin",
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the Edge setting and click the "Advanced settings", under Cookies section, select "Under Cookies section" option, then re-test your application.

If still not working, try to [reset your browser](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4023560/windows-10-what-to-do-if-microsoft-edge-not-working) configuration to default and test your website again.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. But my cookies are set to 'Don't block cookies'